# Brackets on Ubuntu 18.04 - Fonts not displaying properly

Tags: fonts, 18.04, text-editor

I have Brackets on my Ubuntu 18.04 and fonts in menus are looking strange.

I changed the font from the theme editor, but the result is the same.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Brackets with left navigation menu showing poorly rendered fonts]

Comment: If this is the snap then please open an issue [here](https://github.com/snapcrafters/brackets/issues). You can find out if it's the snap by using `which brackets` or inspecting the menu item with Main Menu (`alacarte`).

Comment: $ which brackets  result is: 
/usr/bin/brackets

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

`sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libfreetype6=2.8-0.2ubuntu2.1
sudo apt-mark hold libfreetype6`


*What this code does is downgrade libfreetype6:amd64 from 2.8.1-2ubuntu2 to 2.8-0.2ubuntu2.1*

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's an old topic but I found a fast solution. Just install this `.deb` package:

[Link to the package](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20170630T215111Z/pool/main/f/freetype/libfreetype6_2.8-0.2_amd64.deb)

I found this in this link:
https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/14610